# Where is "Update modules list" in Odoo v8?

Tags: odoo

In OpenERP 7, to load a new module, you would go to Settings / Modules / **Update Modules List**, but where is "Update Modules List" in Odoo version 8?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Have you given Technical Features rights to users??

If not then give it [like this](https://www.odoo.com/es_ES/forum/help-1/question/how-to-activate-the-technical-features-7650):

*To activate the technical features, you have to add access rights to your user. You must edit your current user from the menu Settings > Users. Edit your user (probably admin) and, in the Access Rights tab, check the option Technical Features.*

Then, update Modules List menu going to **Settings/Modules/Update Modules List**

Comment: Thanks; so I now know: "Update Modules List" does not appear unless your user has "Technical Features" ticked; this restriction also applies to the Admin user.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using odoo8 we can enable technical settings for update module list, But in odoo9 and odoo10 we need to activate a developer mode for update module list option.

Answer (score 0):

You just change in url : 
This user mode:
http://localhost:8069/web#menu_id=69&action=76

You are automatic To activate the technical features:
http://localhost:8069/web**?debug**#menu_id=69&action=76

**Note :** This is any api of odoo work not need to found To activate the technical features or to activate a developer mode

than go the the:
 **Settings/Modules/Update Modules List**